# Enabled address sanitizer causes problems with Runtime.InteropServices

Tags: c#, c++

In my project I have a .net 6.0 C# wpf app and an unmanaged C++ dll. To detect memory errors, I enabled the 'address sanitizer' option (EnableASAN) in the C++ dll project. This now causes exceptions in Runtime.InteropServices in the C++ and C# interop area (C# adds a callback to a C++ observer).

Is the option ASAN in general not to be activated if iterop is used?

Thanks for any hints!